# Poincaré-type Inequality

Tags: real-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, sobolev-spaces, elliptic-pde

In Lieb's paper "On the lowest eigenvalue of the Laplacian
for the intersection of two domains" one finds the following remark:

> Let $u\in L_{loc}^p(\mathbb{R}^N)$ with $\nabla u \in L^{p}$ and $\|\nabla u\|_{p} \leq 1 .$ Set $k=1+\|u\|_{p}^{-p}\left(\text { for }\|u\|_{p} \leq \infty\right)$. Let $B_{x}$ denote the unitary ball in
>    $\mathbb{R}^N$ centered at $x$, and let $\beta_x$ be its characteristic function. Clearly there is some $x$ such that
>   \begin{equation}
> \label{lb}
> \int|\nabla u|^{p} \beta_{x}<k \int|u|^{p} \beta_{x}.
> \end{equation}

I can't see why this inequality holds.

Answer (score 5):

For $k$ to make sense, we should assume that $\|u\|_p\ne0$. 
Let $l(x)$ and $r(x)$ denote the left- and right-hand sides of your displayed inequality. Then, by Tonelli's theorem, for any real $p>0$
$$\int dx\,l(x)=\int dx\int dz\, 1\{|z-x|<1\}|\nabla u(z)|^p \\
=\int dz\,|\nabla u(z)|^p\int dz\, 1\{|z-x|<1\}
=v_n\|\nabla u\|_p^p\le v_n,$$
where $v_n$ is the volume of the unit ball in $\mathbb R^n$. Similarly,
$$\int dx\,r(x)
=kv_n\|u\|_p^p>v_n.$$
So, 
$$\int dx\,l(x)<\int dx\,r(x)$$ 
and hence 
$$l(x)<r(x)$$
for at least one $x$, as desired.

Comment: Thanks @losifPinelis

Comment: @Pádua : If you are satisfied with this answer, can you please mark it accordingly?